# Cannot drop index from MySQL INNODB table with foreign keys/references

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

I'm about to drop an index from a mySQL INNODB table. There are references defined already. When I try to alter it, it says:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of 'X/#sql-2a5f_219828' to 'X' (errno: 150)
```

Which at first seems logical, since there are relations, it can't be renamed. But even if I disable foreign key checking:

`SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

`ALTER TABLE flyers DROP INDEX Index_5, ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;`

I get the same! I don't want to drop ALL foreign key definitions, drop that index, and define them again! Another solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-mea

Answer (score 0):

Create a new index before dropping the old one.

Comment: what has a new index has to do with the old one?

Comment: My answer may be incorrect if it does not help for you. I recently faced a situation where I had a foreign key referring to a column in another table and wanted to change/re-create the index for that column. I was not able to get rid of the old index, but after I first created a new index (basically a duplicate of the original index) I was able to drop the old one. Maybe the error message was different though and this is not related... Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was there was already an index on the foreign key field :) and I didnt know that foreign key is also an index. Anyway I ripped all my hair out in the end, I had to drop all indexes to get rid of it. I will never use innoDB again